# Node: how to write route controller

Tags: node.js, routes, mern

I am currently learning MERN and after following a few tutorials I was wondering what were the best practices concerning the routing setup on the back-end.

1. Is it really useful/important to separate routes from their logic ?
2. What is the best practice concerning the controller (that's what the teacher called the logic on the routing)

```
(req, res) => {
  Exercise.find()
    .then(exercises => res.json(exercises))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

Or

```
(req, res) => {
    try {
        const exercises = Exercises.find();

        res.status(200).json(exercises);
    } catch {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it really useful/important to separate routes from their logic ?

I'm not going to go into detail. But there is a concept of controllers, route configs, and views that helps to show a clear separation of responsibilities. Route configs are responsible for initializing and associating routes with controllers. Controllers are responsible for taking the inputs from the route and invoking the appropriate actions to execute. These actions can be anything such as involve rendering a view or calling a service if this particular controller is responsible for an API endpoint.

> What is the best practice concerning the controller (that's what the
> teacher called the logic on the routing)

There is no best or worst way of writing if you are following recommended practices of using anything.

for example, as long as you are using one or two then's, it seems fine you can actually able to debug if there is any error and also it is readable:

```
(req, res) => {
  Exercise.find()
    .then(exercises => res.json(exercises))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

But, if you have several then's nested in each other it will be really difficult to debug:

```
  Exercise.find()
    .then(exercises => {res.json(exercises) 
     })
    .then(exercises => {res.json(exercises); 
    .// more steps to get the final values.
    .
    .then(exercises => {res.json(exercises); 
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
```

Now, this piece of code :

```
(req, res) => {
    try {
        const exercises = Exercises.find();

        res.status(200).json(exercises);
    } catch {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}
```

You won't be able to get the value in `exercises` as it is a promise which has to be resolved or rejected in order to get the values. Also, try/catch won't work here as this is asynchronous code and you won't be able to catch the errors. To check the errors and values you need to use the then/catch notation which is the above one.

However, we can simplify this existing code by using async/await where you can use try/catch :

```
async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const exercises = await Exercises.find();
        res.status(200).json(exercises);
    } catch {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}
```

For more details, I would recommend you to go through this [link](https://medium.com/@dio.hamidou/async-await-vs-then-catch-4f64d42e6392).

Comment: To be fair the teacher did (thank god) use async and await, I rewrote it quickly to only show the difference in syntax that I was wondering about without knowing it was imperative in this solution.

Thanks for the explanation I'll go and read the article right now